# How to define a variable of type BYTE in C header?

Tags: c, data-structures

My main program uses a variable that stores the pointer to a byte.

How would I define that in the header?

Comment: If I understand you right then unsigned char *

Comment: Based on your series of questions tonight, you might find these useful, [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use C99, you could do:

```
#include <stdint.h>


uint8_t *pointer_to_byte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Byte is not a standard type but on many system any unsigned char will do the job on windows which I am more familiar there is a typedef for BYTE which is available in the windows headders

Comment: So unsigned char will do on UNIX/OSX?

Comment: In general unsiged char will work but its not assured to be only a byte only that its big enough to hold a character.

Comment: so it would be something like #define unsigned char myPointerVariable?

Comment: @antonpug: No, stop using `#define`, that is used to create preprocessor macros. You would say `unsigned char *myPointerVariable`

Comment: use a typedef over define.  define is really to suss out issues where you want to be able to change the code at complie time

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing something which relates to generic programming,you should use the void *.
for most of the systems though you can use unsigned char *.